# Add Datetime and time in Entity Framework from separate column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I want to get all the events which are not ended yet

```
select * FROM [Events] where EndDate+cast(EndTo as datetime)>GETDATE()
```

which is working perfectly.

This is my value in (`EndTo: 11:00:00.0000000, END DATE: 2016-05-26`)

I tried using

```
var list = dbContext.Events
                    .Where(e => e.EndDate + e.EndTo > DateTime.Now)
                    .ToList();
```

and I'm getting an error

> DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.

How can I write this query in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you try to add `DateTime` with `TimeSpan`, which is not allowed. To do that, try to use something like `DateTime.AddSeconds(TimeSpan.TotalSeconds)` instead:

```
var list= dbContext.Events
           .Where(e=>e.EndDate.AddSeconds(e.EndTo.TotalSeconds) > DateTime.Now)
           .ToList();
```

Or if this is LINQ to Entities:

```
var list= dbContext.Events
           .Where(e=>EntityFunctions.AddSeconds(e.EndDate, e.EndTo.TotalSeconds) > DateTime.Now)
           .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

Since your `e.EndTo` is a `Nullable<TimeSpan>`, then you should use its `Value`:

```
var list= dbContext.Events
           .Where(e=>e.EndDate.AddSeconds(e.EndTo.Value.TotalSeconds) > DateTime.Now)
           .ToList();
```

Or

```
var list= dbContext.Events
           .Where(e=>EntityFunctions.AddSeconds(e.EndDate, e.EndTo.Value.TotalSeconds) > DateTime.Now)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: Error : 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'TotalSeconds' and no extension method 'TotalSeconds' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @M.Nabeel ah, so your `e.EndTo` is a `Nullable` `TimeSpan`, in that case, please try to use `e.EndTo.Value.TotalSeconds` instead

Comment: @M.Nabeel no problem! ;)

Comment: This doesn't work for Linq to Entities. "'TotalSeconds' is not supported in LINQ to Entities". Additionally `TotalSeconds` is a `double` but `AddSeconds` takes an `int` so it won't even compile as written.